# Whitespace between elements (closing tags and opening tags) in XML?

Tags: xml, sitemap

I have an XML sitemap. Do I need white space between closing tag and opening tags? e.g. should this:

```
/><
```

actually be :

```
/> <
```

or are both okay?

Here's an example of a block of code without the spaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><url><loc>http: //www.ospreyeurope.com/che_de/hiking/tempest-series</loc><lastmod>2016-07-20</lastmod><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.5</priority><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/eu_en/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="en" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/che_de/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="de-ch" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/che_fr/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="fr-ch" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/che_it/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="it-ch" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/be_fr/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="fr-be" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/dk_en/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="en-dk" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/de_de/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="de-de" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/es_es/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="es-es" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/fi_en/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="en-fi" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/fr_fr/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="fr-fr" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/ie_en/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="en-ie" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/it_it/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="it-it" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/lu_fr/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="fr-lu" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/nl_en/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="en-nl" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/no_nb/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="nb-no" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/at_de/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="de-at" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/se_sv/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="sv-se" /><xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ospreyeurope.com/gb_en/hiking/tempest-series" hreflang="en-gb" /></url>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML allows white space to appear between elements; it's up to applications to define whether such whitespace is significant.  In the case of sitemaps, such whitespace is insignificant.